# Issue in the Design View for ASP.Net Custom Server side Control which inherits GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, custom-controls, visual-studio-designer, datafield

I have created a Custom Server Side Control which inherits GridView Class. I have added a public string property, which accepts the column names of the Data Source(DataSet or DataTable) with comma separator. Now I have implemented the required methods(in my case I have overridden the OnRowDataBound Event) and used the custom property values. I have used the same DLL in other projects too. Declared the property as below

```
[Bindable(false)]
public string RowSpanColumn
{
     get { return _RowSpanColumn; }
     set { _RowSpanColumn = value; }
}
```

I have dragged the control on to my ASPX page, the design view of VS looks fine(same as GridView design). But when I am setting the custom property as mentioned above, design view of the control is showing error on top of it as

```
There was an error rendering the control.Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

And the ASPX Page is running perfectly as expected, there is only an issue with design view of Visual Studio. Please help me to find a solution. Thanks

**Update**

We have observed that renaming the Property name to other than RowSpanColumn say RSColumn. The Design is showing perfectly. I wanna know, if RowSpanColumn is predefined property used by Visual Studio? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding design time support for your custom control?

Here are few links that might help.

ASP.NET Control Designers Overview
-- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh45wzs.aspx

Design Time Architecture -- 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5z9s1h4.aspx

Custom Design-time Control Features in Visual Studio .NET -- 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164048.aspx

Extending Design Time Support --
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37899azc.aspx

For more you can try to debug the issue using another instance of visual studio and attach to existing process.

Comment: Thanks @Mitual, I didn't add any design time support for the control. Please check my update, which reveals an interesting observation.

Comment: Thanks, anyways for sharing the good articles on design time support.